# Chrome browserAction setPopup display bug on Linux (Mint)

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am debugging a Chrome Browser Extension in Chrome (Stable Version 21.0.1180.57 - NOT Chromium) on Linux Mint (with XFCE as my desktop environment).

When I click on the extension, the popup originating from it goes upward over the title bar rather than downward into the browser. This makes its contents unviewable without resizing or moving the window.

If, however, I comment out this line in the file, *background.js*: 
`chrome.browserAction.setPopup({"tabId":data.tabId, "popup":url})`

the popup drops down into the browser window like it is supposed to (except it doesn't show our extension's page-specific content).

I tried to take a screenshot, but I couldn't figure how to do so with the popup open.

Comment: If it is a bug with chrome, then you should file a bug at http://crbug.com

Comment: I'm running Chrome Stable Version 21.0.1180.57 - they just released 21.0.1180.75 2 days ago and my browser hasn't yet updated.